# PyCharm does not recognize project modules after copying project

Tags: python, pycharm

I copied my project from my internal SSD to my external HDD. When I open my project now, PyCharm does not recognize it properly. Actually `main` and `main2` are python modules (folders with `__init__.py` files), not just files:

[image]

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
File -> Settings -> Project:projectName -> Project Structure -> +Add content root.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go through the files in the `.idea` folder and look for wrong paths. AFAIK all project settings are stored in that folder, so you should be able to resolve the issue there.

Comment: Practically would be to search for files which have the old root path as part of their content and change those paths to the current root path, right?

Comment: yes, or just go through the files and manually search for wrong paths